# save multiple values as array into variable rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I got a variable in a nested model (`account`) belonging the user model in which there is a column for `:skills`. in my edit_user_path, i would like to be able to save multiple skills into that column via checkboxes. For doing that I permitted the `skills` in the controller as array, even though it is saved as string into the database.

My controller:

```
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :account, 
            account_attributes:[:id, :username, {:skills => []}, :description, :location, :avatar, :tags, :tag_list])
    end
```

If i save multiple values via checkboxes into this variable inside of a nested form, i do it like this:

```
        <% skills = ["Coding", "Design", "Petting Cats"] %>
        <% skills.each do |skill| %>

        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <%= form.check_box :skills, { multiple: true, class:"custom-control-input",id: skill }, skill, false %>
            <%= form.label skill, class:"custom-control-label", for: skill %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <% end %>
```

This works and the values are getting saved as an array, but oddly the array once saved into the database looks like this:

```
"[\"Artist\", \"Mixing\", \"Mastering\"]"
```

instead of this:

```
["Artist", "Mixing", "Mastering"]
```

Which leads to troubles, since i would like to iterate through all users later "filtering" for certain skills, like `User.account.where(skills: "Petting Cats")` if a user has `Petting Cats` saved somewhere inside of the array.

For Development i am using SQLite, for production PostgresQL.
How do i save multiple strings into a string variable as clean array without mess, and how to iterate through the array later with a `where` query method?

Comment: This seems like a uniquely bad idea. You should, IMO, have a `Skill` model and create a `m:m` relationship between `User` and `Skill` using a `UserSkill` join model (using `has_many :through`). Also, you're asking for trouble by developing with SQLite and deploying with PostgreSQL. There are subtle differences that can pop up and cause you heartache. Best to keep development as close to production as possible.

Comment: Is that column set `serialize`?

Comment: @tadman no i dont think so. i havent configured it though.

Comment: @jvillian good point. i have thought of this already but thought it would be an overkill since i only want to store a tiny bit of content. isnt it possible instead of creating a join model, just to go for a one:many relationship between `skill` and `user`? also how would i realize this in a form? since most of the users will have multiple skills i would have to create almost every time two records for skill with one form

Comment: It would be good if you maintain a separate skill table. Tomorrow you may need to add few more fileds related to skill,  (like skill version , level of expertise in that skill)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're falling into the common double whammy noob trap of using an array column and serialize.

The reason you are getting `"[\"Artist\", \"Mixing\", \"Mastering\"]"` stored in is that you are using `serialize` with a native array column. `serialize` is an old hack to store stuff in varchar/text columns and the driver actually natively converts it to an array. When you use serialize with a native array/json/hstore column your actually casting the value into a string before the driver casts it. The result is:

```
["[\"Artist\", \"Mixing\", \"Mastering\"]"]
```

Removing `serialize` will fix the immediate problem but you're still left with a substandard solution compared to actually doing the job right:

```
# rails g model skill name:string:uniq
class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  has_many :user_skills, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_skills
end
```

```
# rails g model user_skill user:belongs_to skill:belongs_to
# use `add_index :user_skills, [:user_id, :skill_id], unique: true` to ensure uniqueness
class UserSkill < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :skill_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_skills, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :skills, through: :user_skills
end
```

```
<%= form_with(model: @user) do |form| %>
  <div class="field"> 
    <%= form.label :skill_ids %>
    <%= form.collection_select :skill_ids, Skill.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(
    :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :account, 
    account_attributes: [
      :id, :username, :description, :location, :avatar, :tags, :tag_list,
    ],
    skill_ids: [] 
 )
end
```

This gives you:

- Queryable data
- Referential integrity
- Normalization
- Encapsulation
- ActiveRecord Assocations!
- The pleasure of not looking like an idiot in a review/audit

Comment: lul this made my day. also thank you for the in detail explaination

Comment: One question. where do you put the `add_index` in the migration or in the model?

Comment: In the migration. In the `def change` method.

Comment: i see. can you explain why you chose putting the param inside of the `account_attributes`, since there is a relation between the `UserSkill` model and the `user` ? Also I am getting an undefined method error for `skill_ids` :S

Comment: I based that on your own user_params method in the question. So thats a question you really should be asking yourself. The most likely reason your getting a no method error is that you havent added `has_many :skills, through: :user_skills` to your User model.

Comment: everything works now so i really thank you for that (its getting late and i forgot to add the association inside of the join model). im just asking for a better understanding. the user has many skills, the skills and user skills belong to the user, yet the strong params for the skills are located inside of the account array in the controller.

Comment: I just assumed that you where using some kind of nested attributes since the code in the question was setup that way. See my edit.

Comment: ah yeah tack min vän